# Trying to understand what is going on at didselectrowatindexpath. App crashes with message index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I'm trying to understand what is going on with my code.

App is crashing when I'm selecting one of the items of my array. Basically, she user selects one row it should open a new tableview with data for that selected row, but it is only working for one row, I'm guessing my array has only one result when I filter (search bar), and when I click object at index 1 it crashes. But that's just a guess, I couldn't fix it.

I have two `NSArrays`.

```
@implementation BuscaDadosNoBanco

{
   NSArray *searchResults;
   NSArray *todosUsuarios;
}
```

Here is the code for the table:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [todosUsuarios count];

   }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
        NSLog(@"%@", _arrayComDados);

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueDetalhesUsuario" sender: self];
    }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueDetalhesUsuario"]) {
       DetalhesUsuario *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

       NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
       if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
           indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           Usuario *usuario = [[Usuario alloc] init];
           [usuario recuperaDadosUsuario:_arrayComDados eEmail:[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
           destViewController.dadosUsuario = usuario;

       } else {
           indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           destViewController.dadosUsuario = [todosUsuarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }
   }

  }

   - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
   {
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"usuario.username contains [cd] %@", searchText];
   NSArray *filtroUsuario = [_arrayComDados filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
   searchResults = [filtroUsuario valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.usuario.username"];
   NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
}

      #pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
     -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
     shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
        {
         [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

         return YES;
     }

    - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
  {
      [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

   return YES;
  }
```

Whenever I type the right letter in the search bar, the log shows one email string like `"blabla@bla.com"`. I have two items in my array, one is working when I select it populates the next tableview correctly, but when I try the other one, although it shows the correct email in the log, the app crashes with the message: `-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`.

Please let me know if you need any other information. I really need help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Please add an exception breakpoint, this will then stop on the exact line of code where the crash occurs. Go to the breakpoints navigator, click add, and choose "Exception breakpoint".

Comment: I don't understand what your looking for from us. Your exception is incredibly clear. you are trying to access index 1 in an array that has only 1 element in it (i.e. it only has an index 0). You need to add error checking to see is the current index greater than the available number of elements

Comment: Thanks @jrturton, the breakpoint took me to a different class. The crash is related to object at index, but for populating the detail tableview, not the one in question. I didn't solve it yet, but I'm closer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Issue in Your code!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];
} else {
    return [todosUsuarios count]; 
}
}
```

here You chech which array use but when You create cell You do not check which array should be used

```
cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

So, You can get situation when count of rows comes from todosUsuarios but elements You trying get from searchResults

Comment: That's probably it. Well spotted!

Comment: The author said it crashes when a row is selected, not when when the cells are being rendered. What you described would only explain why it would crash during the cellForRowAtIndexPath calls.

Comment: I've described only one situation. All that need in this situation - just check where he get object from array. For example: This can happends in prepareForSegue.